# Android card-io could not trigger auto focus

Tags: android, paypal, cardio

I am using card.io-Android -SDk in my application 
when i run the app i am not able to focus camera

Error: could not trigger auto focus: java.lang.RuntimeException: autoFocus failed.

app passed NULL surface
any help?

Answer (score 0):

write this code in your manifest file...

```
  <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
            android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many cards that card.io will not successfully scan.

These include the newer style cards, which lack the traditional large, **embossed** card numbers. 
Even among traditional cards, there are some whose background color or pattern makes scanning difficult.

The issue is that the cards which dont have the **embossed card numbers** card.io wont scan.